# Getting a specific Menu from wordpress to php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 3 menus created in WordPress and the main menu is retrieved using `wp_nav_menu()` . I also want to retrieve the other menu please guide me how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve other menu, you need to pass argument menu with menu name like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'name of the menu' ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass it an args array, and declare the theme_location key.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'header_main'
) ):
```

and

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'header_secondary'
) ):
```

Answer (score 2):

You are able to create custom menu in your theme. Add this code to the function.php of your theme.

```
function lanparts_menu_setup(){
    add_theme_support('menus','woocommerce');       
    register_nav_menu('woocommercemenu','Woocommerce Menu Navigation');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme','lanparts_menu_setup');
```

for more detail that follow this [link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/)